# SQL statement to check if data exists in one table and not in two other tables

Tags: sql

I'm creating 1 temp table (temp1) using table1.
and I want to check if data from temp table is present in table1 and table2.

table1 and table2 have same columns.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to assess exactly what you need without further detail, but you could try a LEFT JOIN and a COUNT here to indicate whether there are any matching rows (whereby anything over 0 indicates matching rows)

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS matching_rows

FROM
  (
    SELECT 
    1 AS 'ColumnA'
  ) AS T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
    2 AS 'ColumnA'
  ) AS T2
  ON T1.ColumnA = T2.ColumnA

 WHERE
 T2.ColumnA IS NOT NULL
```

You can also use an INNER JOIN for this:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS matching_rows

FROM
  (
    SELECT 
    1 AS 'ColumnA'
  ) AS T1
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
    2 AS 'ColumnA'      
  ) AS T2
  ON T1.ColumnA = T2.ColumnA
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NOT NULL` is an `INNER JOIN`, so this is quite not educative, but an unnecessary complication.